# How to auto wrap text with a dash in it?

Tags: c++, qt

In `QStyledItemDelegate` subclass `paint` method, the following code does not wrap the date-text as expected:

```
int flags = Qt::AlignCenter | Qt::TextWordWrap | Qt::TextJustificationForced;
switch (index.column())
    {
    case TimeRole:
    {
        int boxW = 16, space = 5, leftSpace = 30;
        QRect textRect = QRect(rect.left() + leftSpace + boxW + space, rect.top(), rect.width() - boxW - space - m_space - leftSpace, rect.height());

        QDateTime time = QDateTime::fromMSecsSinceEpoch(model->m_eventTime);
        QString timeStr = time.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        painter->drawText(textRect, flags, timeStr);
        break;
    }
```

However, I think because there is a dash `-`, text does not wrap as expected, instead, the left and the right characters are hidden:

[image: display error]

Comment: `-` is dash or hyphen. `/` is slash.

Comment: The rectangle is too small. That is why the text is not displayed completely.

Comment: @V.K.When text is "abcdef...", it automatically enlarges rectangle to hold them. But when text is date with a hyphen `-`, rectangle does not wrap them, and displays them in one line. `2020-02-02`, I want it to be `2020\n-02-\n02` >_<

Comment: Why you don't alter the timeStr and add the new line tokens at the desired locations?

Comment: @osbuilder I finally solved this problem by comparing rect.width() with an experimental value, if it is smaller than that value, add `Qt::TextWrapAnywhere` to flag. The same rect width comparison also works for different screen resolution.